# Why is cmake linking to opencv in conda environment when I have specified the path to opencv 4 installation?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, cmake, c++14, conda

I'm trying to run the sample dnn program from [opencv's website for object detection](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d4/db9/samples_2dnn_2object_detection_8cpp-example.html)

Here's what my CMakeLists.txt looks like:

```
project( IOT_MINI )
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
SET(OpenCV DIR /usr/local/include/opencv4)
find_package(OpenCV 4 REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

message(STATUS "OpenCV library status:")
message(STATUS "    config: ${OpenCV_DIR}")
message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")


add_executable( Dog_detector Dog_detector.cpp )
target_link_libraries( Dog_detector ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

I can successfully find OpenCv 4. `cmake ..` runs successfully. But while `make` it links(?) to conda environment.
I don't know how to reproduce this exactly since I have ROS, conda and opencv installed and I don't know what exactly is causing the problem.

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target Dog_detector
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Dog_detector.dir/Dog_detector.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable Dog_detector
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.0.0, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.0.0, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libcairo.so.2, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.0.0, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: warning: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.0.0, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `avio_close@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gst_app_src_push_buffer'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `dc1394_capture_setup'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `png_set_write_fn@PNG16_0'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gtk_window_get_title'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `av_seek_frame@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `jas_matrix_destroy'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gtk_widget_new'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_decompress@LIBJPEG_8.0'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gzclose'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_src@LIBJPEG_8.0'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gtk_file_chooser_set_do_overwrite_confirmation'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gzgets'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `av_frame_free@LIBAVUTIL_55'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gtk_init'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `png_write_end@PNG16_0'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gst_element_factory_make'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `png_set_packing@PNG16_0'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gst_element_get_static_pad'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `png_read_info@PNG16_0'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `sws_scale@LIBSWSCALE_4'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `dc1394_get_control_registers'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `png_read_image@PNG16_0'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `sws_getCachedContext@LIBSWSCALE_4'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `Imf_2_2::OutputFile::OutputFile(char const*, Imf_2_2::Header const&, int)'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `av_init_packet@LIBAVCODEC_57'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `g_cond_timed_wait'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `av_codec_get_tag@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `jas_cmprof_createfromclrspc'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `jpeg_default_qtables@LIBJPEG_8.0'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gtk_hbox_new'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `TIFFOpen@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `dc1394_video_get_supported_modes'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `Imf_2_2::InputFile::setFrameBuffer(Imf_2_2::FrameBuffer const&)'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gst_encoding_container_profile_new'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gst_bin_iterate_elements'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `av_codec_get_id@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `avformat_open_input@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gst_structure_get_string'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `g_value_unset'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `png_read_end@PNG16_0'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `av_frame_alloc@LIBAVUTIL_55'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gst_is_missing_plugin_message'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gtk_widget_get_events'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `jpeg_write_scanlines@LIBJPEG_8.0'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gtk_window_fullscreen'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `g_type_check_class_cast'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `WebPGetFeaturesInternal'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `avformat_write_header@LIBAVFORMAT_57'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `powf@GLIBC_2.27'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `avcodec_get_name@LIBAVCODEC_57'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gst_encoding_container_profile_add_profile'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gzputs'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gst_bin_iterate_sources'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `png_set_read_fn@PNG16_0'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gtk_hscale_new_with_range'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `png_get_tRNS@PNG16_0'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_dnn.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `expf@GLIBC_2.27'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `png_set_compression_level@PNG16_0'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gdk_cairo_set_source_pixbuf'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `png_set_swap@PNG16_0'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gst_app_sink_get_max_buffers'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `png_init_io@PNG16_0'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `png_set_strip_alpha@PNG16_0'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gtk_widget_set_realized'
/home/atmadeep/.conda/envs/AI/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `gtk_style_set_background'
... [Shortened for brevity]
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/Dog_detector.dir/build.make:98: recipe for target 'Dog_detector' failed
make[2]: *** [Dog_detector] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:75: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Dog_detector.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Dog_detector.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Where did you get the line `SET(OpenCV DIR /usr/local/include/opencv4)`? Have you tried `find_package(OpenCV 4 REQUIRED PATHS /usr/local/include/opencv4)`?

Comment: That didn't help. The error is still the same.

Comment: Yes, as suggested, it appears this line `SET(OpenCV DIR /usr/local/include/opencv4)` is missing an underscore in the variable name, should be `OpenCV_DIR`.

Comment: Jesus lord, that solved the problem. Thank you very much. I didn't know cmake was that picky.